# Creating Address Attribute in Java

Tags: java

```
package week3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class TaxPayer {

private final String TFN;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double income;

private Address address(int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb,
        String city, String state, int postcode);

public TaxPayer(String TFN, String firstName, String lastName, double income,
        Address address) {
    this.TFN = TFN;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.income = income;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public double getIncome() {
    return income;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setIncome(double income) {
    this.income = income;
}

public void setAddress(Address i) {

}

public String getFullName() {
    return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return TFN + " " + firstName + " " + lastName + " "
            + income;
}

public static double calcTax(double income) {
    return 1;
}

public double calcTax() {
    return 1;
}

public static void printArrayListToConsole(ArrayList<TaxPayer> Array) {
    for (TaxPayer d : Array) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}

package week3;

public class Address {

int streetNumber;
String streetName;
String suburb;
String city;
String state;
int postcode;

public Address(int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb,
        String city, String state, int postcode) {

    this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    this.streetName = streetName;
    this.suburb = suburb;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return streetNumber + " " + streetName + " " + suburb + " " + city + " "
            + state + " " + postcode;
 }
}
```

So, my problem is in creating the address attribute, which must be private. I think I've made the other class correctly yet it still isn't working. As well as this, the attribute isn't working with the fields I try to put in it (streetNumber, streetName, etc), it's coming up with the error 'missing method body, or declare abstract' but I'm unsure why. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Address address(int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb,
        String city, String state, int postcode);// this is a method not a attribute
```

Make private attribute of Address Class.

```
public abstract class TaxPayer {
     .
     .
     .
     private Address address; // this is attribute.
     .
     .
     .
    //One way is passing the all address attributes in constructor
    public TaxPayer(String TFN, String firstName, String lastName, double income,int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb,
    String city, String state, int postcode) {
        this.TFN = TFN;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.income = income;
        this.address = new Address(streetNumber, streetName, String suburb,city, state,  postcode);
    }
}
```

second option is use same constructor and make a Address objectin main class and pass into that constructor like :

```
public TaxPayer(String TFN, String firstName, String lastName, double income,Address address) {
        this.TFN = TFN;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.income = income;
        this.address = address;
    }
```

And while creating Tax Payer Object first create Address Object and pass it.

```
Address address= new Address(streetNumber, streetName, String suburb,city, state,  postcode);
TaxPayer tp= new TaxPayer(TFN, firstName, lastName, income,address);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Address address(int streetNumber, String streetName, String suburb,
    String city, String state, int postcode);
```

- You have to declaring a variable of Address type but this is not the way to declare a variable.
- Replace the above code of TaxPayer class with just this
- private Address address;